# When and how to use form methods

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am reading the Django documentation and ran across a couple examples in the forms sections that I do not understand why they did something 2 separate ways..

In the [first example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/#more-on-fields) I found they send email from the FBV. This makes a lot of sense to a beginner:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

if form.is_valid():
    subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
    message = form.cleaned_data['message']
    sender = form.cleaned_data['sender']
    cc_myself = form.cleaned_data['cc_myself']

    recipients = ['info@example.com']
    if cc_myself:
        recipients.append(sender)

    send_mail(subject, message, sender, recipients)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
```

In the [second example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#basic-forms) I found they use CBVs and apply methods to the form and call this method in the view:

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    def send_email(self):
        # send email using the self.cleaned_data dictionary
        pass
```

```
from myapp.forms import ContactForm
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

class ContactView(FormView):
    template_name = 'contact.html'
    form_class = ContactForm
    success_url = '/thanks/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # This method is called when valid form data has been POSTed.
        # It should return an HttpResponse.
        form.send_email()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

When should you apply form methods and call those methods in the view? Is there a benefit to writing the code this way?

Also, in the second example they used `pass` in the `send_email()` method. I wanted to investigate further so I applied this to simple invite form I had..

```
class InviteForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    phone = PhoneNumberField(help_text='Format must be: +15595551234', required=False)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    subject = forms.CharField()
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    def send_email(self):
        send_mail(self.subject, self.message, 'someone@company.com', [self.email])
```

```
class InviteView(FormView):
    template_name = 'invite/invite_form.html'
    form_class = InviteForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('overview')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.send_email()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Issue here is that I get:

> AttributeError at /invite/
>   'InviteForm' object has no attribute 'subject'

Do I have to create parameters and pass them as arguments in the view after pulling the forms `cleaned_data`? If so, what is the point of creating the form method?

Comment: As the error says, the form doesn't have an attribute `subject`. In your `send_mail()` method, replace `self.subject` by `self.cleaned_data['subject']` (and same for `message` and `email`).

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Dumb mistake. Now I see how it can be useful to use form methods - similar to model methods.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a "correct" way of doing this. One could argue for doing this in the view but there are also good arguments to be made why `send_mail` should be part of the form.

Personally I like to keep my views as concise as possible. This is the first thing you read when you try to understand the behavior of the app. By just writing `form.send_mail()` it's clear that an email will be sent based on the data passed to the form. How this is done is nicely hidden and not really of concern to the view.

If you then later want to change what gets sent in the email, all the functionality is in one place, the form: the fields to populate and the send_mail functionality.

Comment: That is great explanation of your thought process and will help me as I continue to learn. Also, it feels like if you are sending an email of particular form data then this operation is being applied to the form and should therefore be a method of the form. Thank you for taking the time to help clarify the thought process, I am now seeing it more clearly.

Comment: I just realized your thought process goes with "fat models, skinny views" which really helps clarify some things for me. Thanks!

Comment: A `Form` isn't really a model. Forms can contain a lot of business logic, generally in their `clean()` and `save()` methods. In this particular case, since this isn't a `ModelForm` (no save), you can view the `send_email()` as the form's way of being saved/persisted. To me they are the bridge between the views and the models.

Comment: Ahh got it. So model methods should run functions on database data but if a form is collecting data from the user then the method or function should be using the forms `cleaned_data`. Where we get the data depends on if we are saving the data or not.